# How to increase FSB speed from 1066 to 1333 Mhz on Award BIOS?

Tags: cpu, bios, xeon, fsb, lga775

How to increase FSB speed from 1066 to 1333 Mhz on Award BIOS? My motherboard is [this](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-945GCM-S2L-rev-10#ov). I bought a Xeon X5450 CPU which works on LGA 775 but I didn't notice that 4 cores CPU isn't supported by [BIOS](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-945GCM-S2L-rev-10#ov). When I try to boot PC on this CPU, sometimes it gets stuck at the motherboard screen and shows the name of CPU and in other line something like CPUID... Sometimes it turns off instantly without any screen.

I'll try to add Xeon [microcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQQN.jpg), but first of all I want to know how to overclock FSB to 1333Mhz and I want to be sure if it will be OK for my DDR2 RAM. There are some photos of my BIOS. I would also like to know if these modification are worth doing, or maybe I should return that CPU back and buy one that is normally supported by my motherboard. I bought the CPU from [here](https://a.aliexpress.com/_Bf6MjIA5).

BIOS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your motherboard supports setting the multiple to any of those three values.

Comment: Your motherboard will run at whatever the multiplier is set at.  If you don't have 1333 MHz (or faster) then it won't run at 1333 Mhz if it's set to auto.